# Unable to process large PDF file

Tags: java, itext, heap-memory, ioexception

I have jave file with size 160MB.

When I try to load it in PdfReader (Itext Library) it fire following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Not enough storage is available to process this command
```

I am using Java Version 1.5 (32bit).

Code:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = null;
    try{
            pdfReader = new PdfReader("D://bigfile.pdf");

            //also try using  pdfReader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray("D://bigfile.pdf"),null);
    }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have set following heap size parameters:

```
-Xms1000m -Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

I am getting following heap statistics before loading file in PdfReader:

```
##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####
Used Memory:70
Free Memory:921
Total Memory:992
Max Memory:1016**
```

Comment: Do you he enough *storage space*?

Comment: Please check my question i am already printing Heap Statistics.

Comment: I mean *disk* storage, not *memory*.

Comment: yes, it is more than 32 GB free

Comment: On your data partition or on your system partition?

Comment: Both have enough memory ( System partition 160GB free)

Comment: This will use as much memory as the JVM has been allocated. You need to use a profiler to work out how much memory the JVM is attempting to consume in the *Object Representation* of that PDF file. iText develops an object tree that *represents* the data. It is not the same as the data.

Comment: but, There is a approx. 921 MB free

Comment: What's the full stacktrace ?

Comment: Have you checked which update of your JRE you use? There had been some Java revisions which had memory allocation issues. That been said,  if opening large PDFs in a `PdfReader`, you might want to consider opening them in partial mode; that makes iText only load the file parts needed for the operations at hand.

Comment: *i am using Java 1.5* - That was clear from you question already. Which update, which patch exactly?

Comment: Hello @mkl if i use Document.plainRandomAccess=true; then there is no problem.is it safe to use this.

Comment: i am using 1.5.16 update

Comment: Thanks to all, finally found solution.

Comment: @ButaniVijay *if i use Document.plainRandomAccess=true; then there is no problem.is it safe to use this* - Yes. It may be a tiny bit slower but it is safe. This indicates that there are some issues with the memory mapping of files in your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am wring answer to my own question so it can be helpful to other.

i have solved problem Using below code (`using Document.plainRandomAccess=true;)`:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = null;
    try{
            Document.plainRandomAccess=true;
            pdfReader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray("D://bigfile.pdf"),null);
    }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: new RandomAccessFileOrArray(String) is deprecated.Is there any alternative for this?